# Setup very remote server

Tags: server

I'm about to ship a small Ubuntu 18.04.3 server to literally the other side of the earth.

A few days ago, an unattended update from 4.15.0-55 to 4.15.0-58 caused a reboot to hang. The default entry in the grub pointed to the new corrupted instance and therefore I had to connect a screen and keyboard to be able to boot.

What is the best way to configure an Ubuntu server to avoid loss of remote access over ssh?

I can instruct someone on-site to do a power toggle, but unfortunately not more than that.

Comment: Not a Ubuntu answer, but what you need is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management

Comment: Seems like a possible use case for [Ubuntu Core](https://ubuntu.com/core), a 100% snap-based system. Snaps are *specifically* designed to avoid remote hangs or crashes due to a bad upgrade. If a snap upgrade fails or is corrupted, the older (working) snap will be used. Note that deb packages DON'T work on Ubuntu Core, so it's not for everybody.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-core-18-released-for-secure-reliable-iot-devices

Comment: Thanks, Ubuntu Core seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Out-of-band Management too. It seems you can get them as USB sticks, which would be a simple solution.